# Can we define continuity in this way?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that we have some real function of a real variable defined over some interval $I$.

The usual epsilon-delta definition of continuity is that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $x \in I$ if $|x-x_0|< \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \varepsilon$.

But can we "reverse" this and define continuity in this way:

> $f$ is continuous at $f(x_0)$ if for every $\delta >0$ (which is such that it is chosen in the way that we stay inside an interval $I$) there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that if $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \varepsilon$ then $|x-x_0|< \delta$.

Are there any problems with this definition and is every $f$ which is continuous at $x_0$ also continuous at $f(x_0)$, and vice versa?

Comment: I would think that the constant functions should qualify as continuous, don't you?  If you take $f(x)=0$, the simplest constant function, $\delta=1$, $x_0=0$ and $x=10$, no such $\epsilon$ exists since you $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0<\epsilon$ but $|x-x_0|>\delta$ for all $\epsilon$ (*or for arbitrary interval, just take $\delta$ to be a quarter of the interval length and take $x$ to be half of the interval length away from $x_0$ in whichever direction works*)

Comment: Does the negation means discontinuity.

Comment: @JMoravitz Would strictly monotone functions obey this "reversed" definition?

Comment: *strictly* monotone functions look like they might work, but I still expect counterexamples, but that is about it... any function which is not one-to-one will fail, badly.  Consider $f(x)=\begin{cases}1+x&\text{for}~x\geq 1\\ x&\text{for}~x<1\end{cases}$.  This is not continuous by the ordinary definition but appears to be based on yours, for each $\delta$ you may pick $\epsilon=\delta$ to satisfy the properties.

Comment: As for strictly monotone, consider $e^{-x}$, in the neighborhood of $-\infty$